# After Clicking any button all other button are disabled in RecyclerView

Tags: android, button, android-recyclerview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFQ6v.jpg)

Please Refer the Above Image

```
public class complaintAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
private Context context;
String hello, status, type;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
public String service, typeid;
String result_reso;
List<DataComplaint> data= Collections.emptyList();
DataComplaint current;
int currentPos=0;
MyHolder holder;

public complaintAdapter(Context context, List<DataComplaint> data, String service_id, String type_id){
    this.context=context;
    inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data=data;
    this.service = service_id;
    this.typeid = type_id;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.container_complaint, viewGroup, false );
        holder = new MyHolder( view );
        Log.e( TAG, "holder = " + typeid );
    return holder;
}




public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

    final MyHolder myHolder= (MyHolder) viewHolder;
    final DataComplaint current=data.get(i);

    myHolder.textcomplaint.setText(current.complaint);
    myHolder.textaddress.setText("Reason: " + current.address);
    myHolder.textType.setText("Client   : " + current.complaint_type);
    myHolder.textplace.setText("Location: " + current.location);
    myHolder.textticket.setText( current.ticket );
    final int value = getItemCount();
    if(typeid.equals( "history" )){
        myHolder.btn.setVisibility( View.GONE );
        myHolder.btn1.setVisibility( View.GONE );
        myHolder.btn2.setVisibility( View.GONE );
    }
    //  myHolder.textPrice.setTextColor( ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent));
    if(typeid.equals( "pending" )) {
        myHolder.btn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int btn_position = myHolder.getLayoutPosition();
                Log.e( TAG, "total position" +btn_position );

                Button button = (Button) v;
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss " );
                String time = format.format( calendar.getTime() );
                type = "In-transit";
                String tickeid = current.ticket;
                Log.e( TAG, "hello = " + service );
                new BackgroundWorker().execute( time, service, tickeid, type );
                button.setVisibility( View.GONE );
                myHolder.btn1.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                myHolder.btn2.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );





            }
        } );
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}


class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView textcomplaint;
    TextView textaddress;
    TextView textType,textplace, textticket, textreso;
    Button btn, btn1, btn2;
    int value1;

    // create constructor to get widget reference
    public MyHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
            textcomplaint = (TextView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.textcomplaint );
            textaddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.textaddress );
            textType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.textType );
            textticket = (TextView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.ticketid );
            textplace = (TextView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.textplace );
            btn = (Button) itemView.findViewById( R.id.enter );
            btn1 = (Button) itemView.findViewById( R.id.repositry );
            btn2 = (Button) itemView.findViewById( R.id.exit );
    }

}
```

Here is My XML File

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="10dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textcomplaint"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ticketid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textaddress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textType"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_purple"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textplace"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/enter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="In-Trainsit" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/repositry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Reached"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/exit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Logout"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here My Total ItemCount is 8 and My button position starts from 0

Now When I click on 0 positioned button all the other 1,2,3,4... positioned button should disabled

How to Do that

And I only want to use Button No checkbox and no toggle or Switches

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I think you go with the checkbox instead of button

Comment: It can't be done with button? @Sniffer

Comment: @AbhinavGupta I have added the xml file and viewholder

Comment: Actually i Have set there visibility gone But that not want i want 
I want all my In-Transit button should be disable that it @AbhinavGupta

Answer (score 0):

Set the currentPos varible to the clicked position in onClick of the button and call notifyDatasetChanged. Also in onBindViewHolder add below code to enable / disable button based on currentPos

```
myHolder.btn.setEnabled(position == currentPos)
```

If you want all buttons to be enabled at first, initial value of currentPos must be -1(Value less than 0)
also add an extra check like

```
myHolder.btn.setEnabled(position == currentPos || currentPos == -1)
```

Final code would be

```
public class complaintAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
private Context context;
String hello, status, type;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
public String service, typeid;
String result_reso;
List<DataComplaint> data= Collections.emptyList();
DataComplaint current;
int currentPos=-1;
MyHolder holder;

public complaintAdapter(Context context, List<DataComplaint> data, String service_id, String type_id){
    this.context=context;
    inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data=data;
    this.service = service_id;
    this.typeid = type_id;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.container_complaint, viewGroup, false );
        holder = new MyHolder( view );
        Log.e( TAG, "holder = " + typeid );
    return holder;
}




public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

    final MyHolder myHolder= (MyHolder) viewHolder;
    final DataComplaint current=data.get(i);

   myHolder.btn.setEnabled(i== currentPos || currentPos == -1)

    myHolder.textcomplaint.setText(current.complaint);
    myHolder.textaddress.setText("Reason: " + current.address);
    myHolder.textType.setText("Client   : " + current.complaint_type);
    myHolder.textplace.setText("Location: " + current.location);
    myHolder.textticket.setText( current.ticket );
    final int value = getItemCount();
    if(typeid.equals( "history" )){
        myHolder.btn.setVisibility( View.GONE );
        myHolder.btn1.setVisibility( View.GONE );
        myHolder.btn2.setVisibility( View.GONE );
    }
    //  myHolder.textPrice.setTextColor( ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent));




    if(typeid.equals( "pending" )) {
        myHolder.btn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int btn_position = myHolder.getLayoutPosition();
                Log.e( TAG, "total position" +btn_position );

                Button button = (Button) v;
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss " );
                String time = format.format( calendar.getTime() );
                type = "In-transit";
                String tickeid = current.ticket;
                Log.e( TAG, "hello = " + service );
                new BackgroundWorker().execute( time, service, tickeid, type );
                button.setVisibility( View.GONE );
                myHolder.btn1.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                myHolder.btn2.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                currentPos = i;
                notifyDataSetChanged();





            }
        } );
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}


class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView textcomplaint;
    TextView textaddress;
    TextView textType,textplace, textticket, textreso;
    Button btn, btn1, btn2;
    int value1;

    // create constructor to get widget reference
    public MyHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
            textcomplaint = (TextView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.textcomplaint );
            textaddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.textaddress );
            textType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.textType );
            textticket = (TextView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.ticketid );
            textplace = (TextView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.textplace );
            btn = (Button) itemView.findViewById( R.id.enter );
            btn1 = (Button) itemView.findViewById( R.id.repositry );
            btn2 = (Button) itemView.findViewById( R.id.exit );
    }

}
```

Comment: Can You Please Make the Changes you have said in My given Code 
Actually I am not getting it

Comment: In This Way it will disable all my other button??

Comment: It should, please try

Comment: What is the problem you are experiencing??

Comment: None of buttons where disabled after clicking 0th position button

Answer (score 0):

In the `Onclicklistner`of the  `buttons` try to call a function passing the value of the postion of the `button`clicked.

Function should look like this :-

```
ArrayList<Bollean) buttonStates = new ArrayList();
void disbleButtonsNotEqualToPos(int pos){

  for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
    {  
       if(i!=pos)
         buttonStates.add(false);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();  //reflect changes

 }
```

And in the `onBindViewHolder()`  use the list(add this for the button) as follows:-

```
if(buttonStates.get(position))
   button.setEnable(true);
else
   button.setEnable(false);



public class complaintAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
private Context context;
String hello, status, type;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
public String service, typeid;
String result_reso;
List<DataComplaint> data= Collections.emptyList();
DataComplaint current;
int currentPos=0;
MyHolder holder;
ArrayList<Bollean> buttonStates = new ArrayList();

public complaintAdapter(Context context, List<DataComplaint> data, String    service_id, String type_id){
this.context=context;
inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
this.data=data;
this.service = service_id;
this.typeid = type_id;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup   viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.container_complaint, viewGroup,     false );
    holder = new MyHolder( view );
    Log.e( TAG, "holder = " + typeid );
    return holder;
    }




 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

final MyHolder myHolder= (MyHolder) viewHolder;
final DataComplaint current=data.get(i);
buttonStates.add(true);
myHolder.textcomplaint.setText(current.complaint);
myHolder.textaddress.setText("Reason: " + current.address);
myHolder.textType.setText("Client   : " + current.complaint_type);
myHolder.textplace.setText("Location: " + current.location);
myHolder.textticket.setText( current.ticket );
final int value = getItemCount();
if(typeid.equals( "history" )){
    myHolder.btn.setVisibility( View.GONE );
    myHolder.btn1.setVisibility( View.GONE );
    myHolder.btn2.setVisibility( View.GONE );
}
//  myHolder.textPrice.setTextColor( ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent));
 if(buttonStates.get(position))
   button.setEnable(true);
 else
   button.setEnable(false);

if(typeid.equals( "pending" )) {
    myHolder.btn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int btn_position = myHolder.getLayoutPosition();
            Log.e( TAG, "total position" +btn_position );
            disbleButtonsNotEqualToPos(btn_position);
            Button button = (Button) v;
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss " );
            String time = format.format( calendar.getTime() );
            type = "In-transit";
            String tickeid = current.ticket;
            Log.e( TAG, "hello = " + service );
            new BackgroundWorker().execute( time, service, tickeid, type );
            button.setVisibility( View.GONE );
            myHolder.btn1.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
            myHolder.btn2.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );





        }
    } );
 public int getItemCount() {
 return data.size();
}


 void disbleButtonsNotEqualToPos(int pos){

  for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
    {  
       if(i!=pos)
         buttonStates.add(false);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();  //reflect changes

  }


class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

TextView textcomplaint;
TextView textaddress;
TextView textType,textplace, textticket, textreso;
Button btn, btn1, btn2;
int value1;

// create constructor to get widget reference
public MyHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
        textcomplaint = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(        R.id.textcomplaint );
        textaddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.textaddress );
        textType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.textType );
        textticket = (TextView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.ticketid );
        textplace = (TextView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.textplace );
        btn = (Button) itemView.findViewById( R.id.enter );
        btn1 = (Button) itemView.findViewById( R.id.repositry );
        btn2 = (Button) itemView.findViewById( R.id.exit );
}

}
```

Comment: Can You Please Make the Changes you have said in My given Code Actually I am not getting it

Comment: you could just add the list and the function in the adapter class , and the seconpart in the onBind.

Comment: have tried making changes in your code , you can  now try it.

Comment: No, The Application keep stopping

Answer (score 0):

override the getViewType() method in recycleview adapter. return only position delete any other code.